# Unable to select all the elements at one time

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Please look into the attached screenshot

I need to select all the data in 1st box at one time.Currently it allows me to select First name and then click on Arrow and then i need to click on Middle name and click on Arrow to move to box 2.I need to do individually for all the data in Box1 to move to Box2.Also i tried drag and drop Its not working Even manually also its not allowing to drag/drop from Box1 to Box2

Can we select all the elements in the box 1 at a time and then click on arrow to move to box2?Please help me out with this issue..

(Note : Below is the Html code for the Box 1)

`
[image]

Comment: Can you show us your Selenium code?

Comment: clicking one option and by Ctrl+A will selecting all manually?

Comment: No Murali.Cntrl A is selecting all the elements in the page.

Comment: Hello Buaban...I wrote code like click on FirstName and then Arrow.After that click on Middle name and then Arrow.I did the same for all the options in Box 1 to move to Box2.But i need to select all the options at a time in Box1 and then click on Arrow once to move to Box2.I wanted to decrease the code with any logic

Comment: I tried this logic        for(i=1;i<=13;i++)
   {
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/form/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/select/option[i]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/form/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input[1]")).click(); Actual xpath for "First name" is "/html/body/div[4]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/form/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/select/option[1]" in the place of 1 i have given "I".But this logic is not working.Any corrections I need to do?.I mentioned second xpath in Line 2 that is for clicking Arrow

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this solution very easy by Jquery.
the following code very useful to you.

```
$().ready(function() 
{
 $('#right_arrow_id').click(function() 
 {
  return 
  !$('#firstboxid_here option:selected').clone(true).appendTo('#second_box_id_here'); 
 });
```

for removing options from second box.

```
 $('#left_arrow_id_here').click(function()  
 { 
  $('#second_box_id_here option:selected').remove(); 
 }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As per provided comment xpath

```
   /html/body/div[4]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/form/table/‌​tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/select/option
```

will retrieve list of all options nothing but list of webelements. so use findElements here and collect that list

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/form/table/‌​tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/select/option")); 

//use loop here
System.out.println(elements .size()); 
for(int i=0;i<=elements .size();i++) { 
//use click on option
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/form/table/‌​tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/select/option")).click();  //it will click first option by default
//write command to click on arrow
 //so it will loop upto list size nothing number of options and always select first and clicks on >>
}
```

thank you,
Murali

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the first xpath "/html/body/div[4]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/form/table/‌​tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/select/option[i]", I understood that it is implemented like a dropdown. Hence, you can use "Select" class in selenium. Please find the below code for the same.

```
// Initializing the Select class
Select names = new Select(driver);

// Retrieving all the options in the dropdown
List<WebElement> allNamesList = names.getOptions();

// Looping through the list
for(WebElement eachName : allNamesList) {
 // Clicking on each element in the first box
 eachName.click();
 // Your Code to click on Arrow button
}
```

Hope this helps.